# PHP query doesn't shows echo values or error

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to echo some simple variable which is fetched frome a mysql table, but it doesn't show anything, even an error. This is the code:

```
 <?PHP
$query_home = $db_connect->QUERY("SELECT * FROM home WHERE id =1");
IF($query_home->num_rows == 1)
{
    $id = $query_home->FETCH_OBJECT()->id;
    $home = $query_home->FETCH_OBJECT()->home;

    $homepage = nl2br($home);
}
?>
<TD>
<?PHP ECHO"$homepage"; ?>
</TD>
```

Comment: This won't print anything if there's no row with `id = 1`.

Comment: What does `echo $query_home->num_rows;` show?

Comment: Note: Just because PHP is case-insensitive does not mean that it's a good idea to arbitrarily UPPER-CASE function calls. Use the canonical form as shown in the documentation: `query()` and `fetch_object`(). Modern HTML also recommends lower-case tags, like `<td>`. The all upper-case form fell out of style in the mid 1990s.

Comment: When troubleshooting things with an "if," I like to include an "else" that echos some debugging text. In this case I'd add `else { echo "Not one row"; }`

Comment: First of all, if you didn't get ONLY one result, your $homepage var will be undefined. Maybe you can receive none results, or you can have duplicates on your database and receive more than one result. If you want to know if the code is entering on the if, do an echo with some random text inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED :

every time you use FETCH_OBJECT() it will change the index of row. so to solve it, you can call it once and put it in variable

```
<?PHP
$query_home = $db_connect->QUERY("SELECT * FROM home WHERE id =1");
IF($query_home->num_rows == 1)
{
    $obj = $query_home->FETCH_OBJECT();
    $id = $obj->id;
    $home = $obj->home;

    $homepage = nl2br($home);
}
?>
<TD>
<?PHP ECHO"$homepage"; ?>
</TD>
```

hopefully it can help you in some way,

have a nice day.

Comment: '$query_home->FETCH_OBJECT()' returns an object, I'm pretty sure. But that var dump is a good idea either way.